# I want to add on checkout page input field, how to add, about what kind of ideas? 2.0

Tags: magento-2.0

I want to add  input field on checkout page, how to add, about what kind of ideas? 2.0

Answer (score -1):

For magento 1.6(-) the file to edit is checkout/onepage/billing.phtml and for magento 1.6(+) you need to edit file persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml. Open the phtml file, find the code
1

```
<?php if ($this->canShip()): ?>
```

and just above the line add this

```
<li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:ssn" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('SSN') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="custom[ssn]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getQuote()->getSsn()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('SSN') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" id="billing:ssn" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </li>
```

So, as you can see we are simply adding a text with name as custom[ssn] and value as `$this->getQuote()->getSsn()` After doing this, you should see a field in billing.phtml as shown Checkout Page Billing Step. You can add this field on any checkout step, it doesn’t matter for my code.